# App closes after lauches IOS - react native

Tags: react-native

> xception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
> Triggered by Thread:  7
>
> Last Exception Backtrace:
> 0   CoreFoundation                        0x7fff20406d34 __exceptionPreprocess + 226
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                       0x7fff201a4a65 objc_exception_throw + 48
> 2   CoreAutoLayout                        0x7fff60b06fe4 -[NSISEngine tryToOptimizeReturningMutuallyExclusiveConstraints] + 0
> 3   CoreAutoLayout                        0x7fff60b0726c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 25
> 4   UIKitCore                             0x7fff255534ba __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 560
> 5   UIKitCore                             0x7fff25553259 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 192
> 6   UIKitCore                             0x7fff255522bf -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 209
> 7   UIKitCore                             0x7fff25553a35 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _layoutEngineCreateIfNecessary] + 65
> 8   UIKitCore                             0x7fff25546a5a -[UIView _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 128
> 9   UIKitCore                             0x7fff25546ff4 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_addConstraint:] + 26
> 10  CoreAutoLayout                        0x7fff60b20962 +[NSLayoutConstraint _addOrRemoveConstraints:activate:] + 426
> 11  UIKitCore                             0x7fff245e7ffc -[_UIToolbarContentView _ensureButtonBar] + 1526
> 12  UIKitCore                             0x7fff245e87d7 -[*UIToolbarContentView updateWithItems:fromOldItems:animate:] + 317
> 13  UIKitCore                             0x7fff245e54ab -[*UIToolbarVisualProviderModernIOS *setViewOwnersAndUpdateContentViewForItems:withOldItems:animated:] + 444
> 14  UIKitCore                             0x7fff245e59f7 -[*UIToolbarVisualProviderModernIOS updateWithItems:fromOldItems:animate:] + 253
> 15  UIKitCore                             0x7fff245d982f -[UIToolbar setItems:animated:] + 287
> 16  inlearning                               0x10e2ac288 UIView.addKeyboardToolbarWithTarget(target:titleText:rightBarButtonConfiguration:previousBarButtonConfiguration:nextBarButtonConfiguration:) + 11016 (IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.swift:455)
> 17  inlearning                               0x10e2ac78b @objc UIView.addKeyboardToolbarWithTarget(target:titleText:rightBarButtonConfiguration:previousBarButtonConfiguration:nextBarButtonConfiguration:) + 219
> 18  inlearning                               0x10e2acb8b UIView.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(*:action:titleText:) + 347 (IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.swift:488)
> 19  inlearning                               0x10e2acc7d @objc UIView.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(*:action:titleText:) + 173
> 20  inlearning                               0x10e2ac99b UIView.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(*:action:shouldShowPlaceholder:) + 443 (IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.swift:481)
> 21  inlearning                               0x10e2aca0c @objc UIView.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(*:action:shouldShowPlaceholder:) + 76
> 22  inlearning                               0x10e26d210 IQKeyboardManager.init() + 3552 (IQKeyboardManager.swift:872)
> 23  inlearning                               0x10e26d71f @objc IQKeyboardManager.init() + 15
> 24  inlearning                               0x10e26c42b IQKeyboardManager.__allocating_init() + 27
> 25  inlearning                               0x10e285f08 one-time initialization function for kbManager + 24 (IQKeyboardManager.swift:179)
> 26  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff20115b25 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
> 27  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff20116cdd *dispatch_once_callout + 20
> 28  inlearning                               0x10e261041 kbManager.unsafeMutableAddressor in Static #1 in static IQKeyboardManager.shared.getter + 49 (IQKeyboardManager.swift:179)
> 29  inlearning                               0x10e260fe9 static IQKeyboardManager.shared.getter + 25 (IQKeyboardManager.swift:183)
> 30  inlearning                               0x10e260fc1 @objc static IQKeyboardManager.shared.getter + 33
> 31  inlearning                               0x10e711f6d -[ReactNativeKeyboardManager setToolbarPreviousNextButtonEnable:] + 109 (ReactNativeKeyboardManager.m:108)
> 32  CoreFoundation                        0x7fff2040d71c **invoking*** + 140
> 33  CoreFoundation                        0x7fff2040aa8f -[NSInvocation invoke] + 305
> 34  CoreFoundation                        0x7fff2040ad22 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 70
> 35  inlearning                               0x10e48e8e6 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2534 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
> 36  inlearning                               0x10e492d8a facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 1402 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
> 37  inlearning                               0x10e49263c facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 156 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
> 38  inlearning                               0x10e492599 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 25 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
> 39  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff201148e4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
> 40  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff20115b25 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
> 41  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff2011c0df _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 753
> 42  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff2011ccc1 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 400
> 43  libdispatch.dylib                     0x7fff2012797b _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 779
> 44  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7fff6fb05fd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
> 45  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7fff6fb04f57 start_wqthread + 15